# Paypal IPN INCOMPLETE status cause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I am new to the paypal api, but have integrated it into my site. Every transaction has 2 receivers using the `adaptive payments api`. Every once in awhile I get an `ipn` response with status of `INCOMPLETE`. Reading the documentation it says this status is because

```
 Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary receivers have not been paid
```

Why would only one transaction work? Only the first recipient is getting the money causing problems. What is the best way to handle this? Anyway to immediately refund the buyer with the first recipients payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse all payments if any of them in the request fail using the reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError parameter.

> xs:boolean (Optional) Whether to reverse parallel payments if an error
>   occurs with a payment. Allowable values are: true – Each parallel
>   payment is reversed if an error occurs false – Only incomplete
>   payments are reversed (default)